# How to print the line-number of a file (source code) at run time execution?

Tags: python, logging, pytest, testcase

I am executing PyTest-testcases, I want to print out the line-number of every statement within that testcase file at run time execution, which shows that line number (statement) 66 is being executed, as shown below.

Meanwhile, it also print out the file name, if any file is being assessed in that statement, i.e opening, reading, deleting, writing, etc.

I need help to get the output in the following format...

```
Executed line number: 66
Executed line number: 67
Executed line number: 68
Global resources used: Path "./../../../aircraft/T37/T37.xml"
Global resources used: Path "./../../../engine/direct.xml"
Executed line number: 69 
     ...
     ...
```

Comment: What is the context of this, from an application point of view? If you want to just see what has been executed place a print directly before and after each statement?

Comment: Sounds like a job for the Python `logging` module. FYI there’s a format spec for line number in log messages.